# How to elegantly protect a method from an uninitialized interface argument

Tags: c#

Given a method parameter of an interface type, how can I protect a method against uninitialized parameters given that a consumer could supply a reference type or an unknown value type, i.e. a struct type that isn't known to the developer at the time of implementation? I do not want to check specific property values of the passed in property. I have done quite a bit of searching on this topic and haven't found exactly the information I'm looking for.

E.g.

```
public interface IFoo {}

// A type I don't know about
public struct FooStruct : IFoo {}

public class FooClass : IFoo {}
```

... in some other class

```
public void DoSomething(IFoo foo)
{
     // Check if foo is null or default of some value type
     // Just like foo == null, this doesn't work for a value type 
     if (foo == default(IFoo)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  You say you don't want to check specific properties, and you're already checking to see if the parameter is null, so.... what is the problem?

Comment: I'd argue that if you are passed `default(FooStruct)` then you should assume that is what was passed. A null object is easily detected as a uninitialised but there is no difference between an unintiatlized struct and one whose values have all be explicitly set to be the same as the unintialized struct. Thus unless you can make assumption on some properties never being default (which you've said you don't want to do) you have to just accept all structs and trust the caller to have done the right thing.

Comment: Checking for null will not help you as a struct will not be null when passed into your method.

Comment: I can’t check for default(FooStruct) because as I said in the question, I don’t know about FooStruct. And besides, I’d like to protect against any other uninitialized value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `structs` that are not `Nullable<T>`, you can compare your struct to a `new MyStruct()` (Activation.CreateInstance below).

```
void Main()
{
    FooStruct fooStruct = new FooStruct() { FooProp = 1234 };
    FooStruct fooStructDefault = default(FooStruct);
    FooClass fooClass = new FooClass();
    FooClass fooClassDefault = default(FooClass);

    IsDefaultIFoo(fooStructDefault).Dump();
    IsDefaultIFoo(fooStruct).Dump();
    IsDefaultIFoo(fooClassDefault).Dump();
    IsDefaultIFoo(fooClass).Dump();

}

public bool IsDefaultIFoo(IFoo foo)
{
    if(foo != null && foo.GetType().IsValueType)
    {
        return foo.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(foo.GetType()));
    }
    else
    {
        return foo == default(IFoo);    
    }   
}

public interface IFoo { }

public struct FooStruct : IFoo
{ 
    public int FooProp { get; set;}
}

public class FooClass : IFoo { }
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: The interesting question in my mind is what happens if you test against `new FooStruct() { FooProp=0 };`? I think (without running the code) that you'd get `true` returned because it is the same as the default but in this case we have explicitly set the value so do we actually want to claim it is the "default"?

Comment: In that case, you'll definitely see `IsDefaultIFoo` return True, because the given struct *is* exactly identical to `new FooStruct() { FooProp=0 }`. There is no difference.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don’t know about FooStruct. I only know about IFoo.

Comment: ‘IsDefaultIFoo’, that is, purely depends on IFoo. No knowledge of anything but the interface there.

Comment: @pep I responded on my phone and my comment was actually for one of the other threads. (Probably EBCAP but who knows.) It never occurred to me to use Activator. I'd love for that to not be necessary but this seems to answer the question pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about initialized values if the method wouldn't actually break because of them. Comparing to `null` is enough, since what you're really doing to trying to throw an earlier exception with the argument name specified, instead of the dreaded and unspecific `NullReferenceException`; the entire purpose of `throw` is to add more specific details so the calling implementation can readily fix what they're doing wrong (or at least report a more informed and thereby meaningful bug). A good example of this is the fact that the Linq method [`Enumerable.Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't bother throwing due to `count`; [anything less than or equal to `0` simply results in an empty collection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,597).

That being said, if there's something invalid about the `FooStruct`, it should be throwing a specific exception for that invalidity, *not* a somewhat misleading `ArgumentNullException`. Consider, for example, that while `default(int)` is `0`, `0` is perfectly valid to be passed into certain methods, and where it's not, we expect `ArgumentOutOfRange` (hopefully with the valid range mentioned) rather than `ArgumentNull` on a value we *know* is (and never will be) `null`

Answer (score 1):

FooStruct will get boxed when passed to a method that accepts an interface that this struct implements, so you can compare it to null. Probably you may want to read about boxing and maybe this article here will be also helpful: [Gotcha-When-Csharp-Structures-Implement-Interfaces](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1023213/Gotcha-When-Csharp-Structures-Implement-Interfaces)

Comment: You can compare it to `null`, yes, but that doesn't help with determining whether the variable references a `default(FooStruct)`.

Comment: You *can* compare to null, but the result will always be false if struct implementing `IFoo` is not `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually helpful to reason about your code in terms of [contracts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

Every method has some preconditions — things that callee should satisfy, and postconditions — things that method guarantees to do on valid input.

For example, in method `divide y by x` `x` should be obviously non zero ant that's a reasonable precondition. And postcondition for this case is that result is less or equal to `y` provided.

You can guarantee valid behavior only on valid input, so there is no sense to throw on default struct value just because it's default — make some specific and reasonable assertions instead.

`ArgumentNullException` is so wide spread just because arguments are usually used somehow, so it makes sense to verify that they are not null, otherwise your method will fail.